# Can I use a 1-year visa and a tourist visa back-to-back in Spain?

Tags: visas, spain, tourist-visas

I'm a Canadian citizen and I have a Youth Mobility Visa in Spain that lasts 1 year. After it expires, is it possible for me to re-enter on a tourist for another 3 months?

For example, if my 1-year visa ends on October 14th, will I:

1. automatically get 3 more months?
2. need to re-enter to get 3 more months?
3. not be able to get the tourist visa at all?

Comment: Under the Schengen codes, you can get three more months automatically, but Spanish national law might require you to leave and re-enter.  In Schengen terminology, though, "visa" is a sticker in your passport, so as a Canadian citizen you won't get a visa; you'll just be present for a visa-free "short stay."

Comment: @phoog Great. I also chatted with an immigration lawyer here and she said I don't need to re-enter.

Comment: Perhaps you should add that as an answer.  I am pretty sure, for example, that Dutch law requires people to leave after their permits expire, and I think German law does as well, though I find it hard to imagine that an Annex II national would be likely to get into trouble for staying no more than an extra 90 days.  It's somewhat frustrating that it's not specified uniformly for the whole Schengen area.

Comment: @cdmckay could you add that as an answer?

Comment: @MarkMayo The issue is that I don't trust the lawyer enough to have other people depend on it.